# Uploading a file like form-data in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post

I have found some answers here that give examples but none seems to work for me..
this is how my postman looks:

[image]

In the code I download the picture from a URL, save it as jpeg inside a folder and then I try to upload that image with a POST request, here is how it looks:

```
var fileName = image.PhotoId + ".jpeg";
            await Task.WhenAll(client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(image.ImageUrl), @"wwwroot\images\"+fileName));
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\images\", "*.jpeg");
         
            var filePath = Path.Combine(@"wwwroot\images\", fileName);
           
            using var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

            var file_content = new ByteArrayContent(new StreamContent(stream).ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            formData.Add(file_content, "file", fileName);
            var res =  await clientAsync.PostAsync(url, formData);
```

problem is the response that I get in the code is an error..:

> {"error_code":6,"error_message":"Sorry, please try a different picture"}

this type of response is the same one I get when trying to upload a pdf instead of a jpeg on postman so I guess the file is getting corrupted in the code somewhere.

would love to get any ideas to where the problem is!

Comment: Try with `var file_content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));     file_content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");` Also remove `Task.WhenAll` as it's useless with only one parameter

Comment: Also, did you check if the downloaded image is correct? Try first with the same image than in postman.

Comment: Niceee it worked @Kalten! what the difference tho..ReadAllBytes vs new StreamContent(stream).ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result both return bytes

Comment: You should try with `var file_content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath))`. As it should be more memory friendly

Comment: It also works, so the only problem was 
 file_content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

Comment: You can write it as answer and I will approve it! thank you very much.

Comment: could you maybe also explain why new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath)) is more memory friendly than new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));